# Why would this PHP call to set the log file path fail?

Tags: php, logging

This block of code:

```
echo ini_get('error_log');
$debug_logfile_path = "/path/to/log";
@ini_set('error_log', $debug_logfile_path);
echo "checking error log<br>";
echo ini_get('error_log');
```

Shows the error log as unchanged.  This just fails on one installation and I can't figure out what the difference is.

*** Update: This installation is running php-fpm, if that provides any clues.

Comment: Can you check the permissions of the ini file?

Comment: You have disabled error reporting with the `@`. Why not remove it and [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?answertab=active#tab-top) to see if it generates an error?

Comment: No additional errors from that removing the @.

Comment: There is no local php.ini file.